# List category/subcategory tree and display its sub-categories in the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, tree, hierarchy

I have a hierarchical table of Regions and sub-regions, and I need to list a tree of regions and sub-regions (which is easy), but also, I need a column that displays, for each region, all the ids of it's sub regions.

For example:

```
id  name        superiorId
-------------------------------
1       RJ          NULL        
2       Tijuca      1           
3       Leblon      1           
4       Gavea       2           
5       Humaita     2           
6       Barra       4
```

I need the result to be something like:

```
id      name        superiorId    sub-regions
-----------------------------------------
1       RJ          NULL        2,3,4,5,6
2       Tijuca      1           4,5,6
3       Leblon      1           null
4       Gavea       2           4
5       Humaita     2           null
6       Barra       4           null
```

I have done that by creating a function that retrieves a STUFF() of a region row,
but when I'm selecting all regions from a country, for example, the query becomes really, really slow, since I execute the function to get the region sons for each region.

Does anybody know how to get that in an optimized way?

The function that "retrieves all the ids as a row" is:

I meant that the function returns all the sub-region's ids as a string, separated by a comma.
The function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getSubRegions (@RegionId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(
select stuff((SELECT CAST( wine_reg.wine_reg_id as varchar)+',' 
from (select wine_reg_id
            , wine_reg_name   
            , wine_region_superior
        from wine_region as t1
        where wine_region_superior = @RegionId
         or exists 
              ( select * 
                 from wine_region as t2
                   where wine_reg_id = t1.wine_region_superior 
                       and (
                          wine_region_superior = @RegionId 

                           ) 
              ) ) wine_reg
ORDER BY wine_reg.wine_reg_name ASC for XML path('')),1,0,'')as Sons)
GO
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense.  Is the second "RJ" supposed to be a "TJ"?  Why does "RJ" in your sample output have sub-regions for 2 through 6 but does not include 7, 8 and 9 which also connect up to "RJ"?  Clean up the data and maybe we can help.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've messed it up when edited... It's fixed

Comment: Maybe it can be printed as a tree?

Comment: Here is a similar question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797072/5730322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we used to make these concatenated lists in the database we took a similar approach to what you are doing at first

then when we looked for speed

```
we made them into CLR functions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a8s4s5dz(v=VS.90).aspx
```

and now our database is only responsible for storing and retrieving data

```
this sort of thing will be in our data layer in the application
```

Comment: I can't figure a way to do that in a fast way, even on the application layer, that thing I want is something that takes some time to be processed.
Having that column would be great for me, since I'm going to serialize a json object with that information.

Comment: did you try to make it a CLR function? what programming language are using for your domain?

Comment: What do you mean by CRL function? I've created that one above (getSubRegions) that returns all subRegions for each region.

I'm programming in Coldfusion. The application calls the query and process it's result to build the JSON file I need. But I could also use Java.

Comment: I added a link about clr functions